# ZeroClipboard on dynamically generate elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zeroclipboard

I have a set of divs that are all dynamically generated. Within them are clipboard icons, that, when clicked, copy the element's data-hash to the clipboard (not yet functional). These icons have the class '.fa-clipboard' from FontAwesome.

**Minimal code:**

```
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var clip = new ZeroClipboard($('.fa-clipboard'), {
            moviePath : 'plugins/ZeroClipboard.swf'
        });

        $(document).on('click', "#content .fa-clipboard", function(){
            //alert(window.location + $(this).data('hash'));
            clip.setText( window.location + $(this).data('hash') );
            clip.glue( this );
        });

    });

    </script>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="content">
                <!--Dynamically generated elements in here-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</head>
</html>
```

The click function works properly, it's just a matter of setting the clipboard.

Comment: Is there any way you can set ZerClipboard upon element creation?

Comment: I'm creating a web-scraping tool, so the HTML is being created in PHP through an ajax call, then set as a divs HTML, so I don't think there is.

Comment: Maybe do it in the AJAX call?